# ¿Cómo se accede al contenido de una celda de la siguiente tabla en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo se accede al contenido de una celda de la siguiente tabla en javascript? Hola, en concreto quiero que cuando dé click a Prueba1 salte un alert con el id de la celda de la tabla del divpadre, es decir, de Prueba1. Sé que es una pregunta sencilla pero no logro acceder a ella. Muchas gracias de antemano.

dudaforo.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "divpadre">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id = "labelpadre" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF' onclick = "selectcuadro('divpadre');">
                        Prueba1
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id = "divhijo">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label id = "labelhijo" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF'>
                            Prueba2
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dudaforo.js"></script>
</body>
```

dudaforo.js:

```
function selectcuadro(iddiv) {
    alert("id " + document.getElementById(iddiv).childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("id"));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

la cantidad de los .parentNode es dependiendo de cuantos elementos padres tiene antes de llegar al divPadre

```js
function selectcuadro (label) {
  
  let padreLabel = ((((label.parentNode).parentNode).parentNode).parentNode).parentNode;
  
  alert('id: ' + padreLabel.id)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "divpadre">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id = "labelpadre" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF' onclick = "selectcuadro(this);">
                        Prueba1
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id = "divhijo">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label id = "labelhijo" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF'>
                            Prueba2
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dudaforo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez algo así sería más sencillo, y funcionaría siempre sin importar la cantidad de elementos intermedios que haya:

```js
function selectcuadro (label) {

  const padreDiv = label.closest('div');
  
  alert('id: ' + padreDiv.id)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "divpadre">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id = "labelpadre" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF' onclick = "selectcuadro(this);">
                        Prueba1
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id = "divhijo">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label id = "labelhijo" style = 'width: 400px; height: 40px; border-radius: 25px; background-color: #4561FF' onclick = "selectcuadro(this);">
                            Prueba2
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dudaforo.js"></script>
</body>
```

He modificado dos cosas:

- Primero, en vez de pasar el nombre del div padre en la función paso `this`, que hace referencia al elemento en el que se ha pinchado
- Segundo, ahora en la función lo que se hace es usar el método [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) que nos permite pasarle el elemento a buscar, y esto irá subiendo por el árbol hasta dar con el elemento indicado, en este caso solo puse `div`, pero cualquier selector html válido servirá, incluso con clases!

De esta manera, puedes buscar el elemento padre que te interesa sin importar qué tan "abajo" estés en la estructura. Como ves, funciona perfectamente tanto con el divpadre como con el divhijo, siempre te saca el div más "cercano" al elemento que dispara el evento.